# How data are coming into ElasticSearch while running catalogsearch_fulltext?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, elasticsearch, fulltext

I have ElasticSearch as a catalogue search engine. Whenever we are running catalogsearch_fulltext, it is pushing the data into ElasticSearch. I need to do apply a filter to those data before pushing into ElasticSearch.

can anyone point me which file I need to apply filters?

I have tried CLI xDebug with PhpStorm and unable to locate the file where the ElasticSearch gets data.

Thanks.